# Admob Libgdx Gameview stretching

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob, ads

Hello I want to integrate Admob in my LibGdx Game but the problem is if I do this my Game screen is stretching the Gameview I dont want this! i just want to overlap the Ad over the Gameview without stretching the gameview

Here is my Code:

```
 protected AdView adView;
    protected View gameView;
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

    private final int SHOW_ADS = 1;
    private final int HIDE_ADS = 0;

    protected Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case SHOW_ADS: {
                adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            }
            case HIDE_ADS: {
                adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

        cfg.useAccelerometer = false;
        cfg.useCompass = false;
        cfg.useImmersiveMode = true;
        cfg.hideStatusBar = true;

        // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        layout.setLayoutParams(params);

        AdView admobView = createAdView();
        layout.addView(admobView);
        View gameView = createGameView(cfg);
        layout.addView(gameView);

        setContentView(layout);
        startAdvertising(admobView);

        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID_INTERSTITIAL);
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Finished Loading Interstitial", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Closed Interstitial", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private AdView createAdView() {
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID_BANNER);
        adView.setId(12345); // this is an arbitrary id, allows for relative
                                // positioning in createGameView()
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

        adView.setLayoutParams(params);
        adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        return adView;
    }

    private View createGameView(AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg) {
        gameView = initializeForView(new Game(this), cfg);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);


        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, adView.getId());
        gameView.setLayoutParams(params);
        return gameView;
    }

    private void startAdvertising(AdView adView) {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void showOrLoadInterstital() {
        try {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        interstitialAd.show();
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        // "Showing Interstitial", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        AdRequest interstitialRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                                .build();
                        interstitialAd.loadAd(interstitialRequest);
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        // "Loading Interstitial", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (adView != null)
            adView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (adView != null)
            adView.pause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (adView != null)
            adView.destroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void showAds(boolean show) {
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(show ? SHOW_ADS : HIDE_ADS);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you have your question contain only the relevant part(s) of your code instead of the whole thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem recently, it comes from the Layout you are using to display your AdView and your View. The ReLativeLayout will strech the GameView when an Ad is displayed. To avoid that use, a FrameLayout instead of the RelativeLayout. It's very similar.

In your `onCreate()` you'll need this :

```
FrameLayout fLayout = new FrameLayout(this);

FrameLayout.LayoutParams fParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

admobView = createAdView();

View gameView = createGameView(config);
    fLayout.addView(gameView);
    fLayout.addView(admobView);
    setContentView(fLayout);
    startAdvertising(admobView);
```

Be careful to add the `admobView` to the `frameLayout` after adding the `gameView` so your `admobView` overlaps the `gameView`.

Comment: thank you so much it works :) but the gameview and adview in my posted code contains the relativeLayout is it worse or must it be changed to framelayout too ?

Comment: You don't need the RelativeLayout in your case, so you should change to FrameLayout everywhere in your code.

Comment: but it doesent match my params if i do this :/ you you rewrite this code please its not much work on it just 2 or 3 codeline editing more...